# How to create an environment with its embedded commands?

Tags: environments

I would like to create an environment with its commands which can be used like:

```
\begin{myenv}
    \command1
    text paragraph 1

    \command2
    text paragraph 2
\end{myenv}
```

which translates to:

```
\begin{someenv}
    \begin{env1}
        text paragraph 1
    \end{env1}
    \begin{env2}
        text paragraph 2
    \end{env2}
\end{someenv}
```

where `someenv`, `env1` and `env2` are some existing environments in LaTex.

How can I do this?

Comment: I do not understand this question: What should `\command1` and `\command2` do?

Comment: I would like the text after `\command1` to be placed in `env1`, and the text after `command2` to be placed in `env2`.

Comment: That is a bit difficult, but doable if you are willing to allow for a blank line *after* `text paragraph 2` (because then you can use a delimited macro where `\par` is the end delimiter)

Comment: It could be possible with `\newenviron` package and its `\BODY` command (if I remember it correctly)

Comment: I know if I was to use `\command1{text paragraph 1}, the solution would be straightforward. How can I do that allowing blank line after each paragraphs?

Answer (score 2):

Something like this can be done using a `\par` delimited macro (`memoir` is not relevant here, it is just my usual base class)

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}
% note the contents of \mymacro is limited to a single
% paragraph. Because we ue the blank line (paragraph end) as a delimiter
\def\mymacro#1\par{\begin{center}#1\end{center}}

\newenvironment{test}{\par\noindent\hrule\par}{\par\noindent\hrule\par}

\begin{document}

\begin{test}
  \mymacro
  Some long text

  \mymacro
  Some egen longer text

  % above blank line is very important
\end{test}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Would it be possible to use another delimiter? in case the "text paragraph" has blank lines inside it.

Comment: Well, a lot is possible. Personally I prefer to just insert the envs instead. It makes the source a lot more readable. Since I'm using emacs, inserting random envs is a non-issue.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Could you possibly edit the answer to add support for multi-paragraph entry for `\mymacro`?

Comment: No, it it is not possible not in this manner. `\par` is the paragraph marker, and it will react to the first one found. I would stop using the macro approach, and use envs instead. Much much more flexible.